# Weird behavior while setting text property of anchor element

Tags: jquery

I am seeing very strange behavior while setting text property of "a" element using jQuery.

If i used hard coded value for setting text property then it works fine but when i use variable passed as a parameter to function to set the text property it does not work.

Sample:
if i use following code:

```
divToBeCopied.children("[id *='anchor']").text('a@b.com');
```

i can see that the hyper link with text a@b.c

but if i use following

```
function(strEmailAddress)
{
 divToBeCopied.children("[id *='anchor']").text(strEmailAddress);   
}
```

then i simply see hyper link with text 'hyperlink'. I am totally lost. Any help greatly appreciated.

Very interestingly if i simply hardcode the value inside the function then it works like charm

```
function()
{
 var strEmailAddress='tom@a.c'
 divToBeCopied.children("[id *='anchor']").text(strEmailAddress);   
 }
```

Thanks
CSC

Comment: Can you show the code which calls the function?  It may be that which is wrong.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: where you are assigning strEmailAddress ?

Comment: Yea need the code that calls the function

Comment: strEmailAddresses = 'a@b.com;s@3.org';

    var emailAddress = strEmailAddresses.split(';');

    $.each(emailAddress, function () {
      showHyperlink(this);
    })

Comment: Thanks DoctorMick, I found the problem. I was calling function incorrectly.. Here is the right way.  $.each(emailAddress, function (index, value) {
      showHyperLink(value);
    }).. Though i am not sure why alert(strEmailaddress) was displaying the correct value that i was passing..

Answer (score 2):

```
function(strEmailAddress)
{
 alert(strEmailAddress);
 divToBeCopied.children("[id *='anchor']").text(strEmailAddress);   
}
```

You will find the problem yourself.

Comment: i have tried the alert statement before i posted this question and it correctly displays the value passed in the paramerter

Comment: There is no reason this could happen. just for test can you do this strEmailAddress = String(strEmailAddress); or strEmailAddress =jQuery.trim(strEmailAddress); and response quickly if any positive result

Comment: I found the problem. I was calling function incorrectly.. Here is the right way. $.each(emailAddress, function (index, value) { showHyperLink(value); }).. Though i am not sure why alert(strEmailaddress) was displaying the correct value that i was passing..

Comment: I was in deep thought that what possibly could happen and could not find any wrong.I am really relived.Anyways Thank you very much.